# c# access database amount of data error

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I have a Microsoft access 2010 database where I place data in using a richtextbox after one line with 4 words of text that has been formatted I get an error saying "the field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data"
I did set the table rows to 255 characters and I'm only inserting 4 words

Comment: Would you provide us your code please? - the one that is used for inserting data. So we can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Has anyone gotten this error from ADO.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984312/the-field-is-too-small-to-accept-the-amount-of-data-you-attempted-to-add-has-an)

Answer (score 2):

Well, a richtextbox contains formatting information, so it will return a much longer text than what you see in the control.

See this code for example:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Detail_Click()
    MsgBox Me.RichTextBox0.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.RichTextBox0.Value = "Only four words really!"
End Sub
```

This will return:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0\nouicompat{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans Serif;}}
{\*\generator Riched20 15.0.4481}{\*\mmathPr\mwrapIndent1440 }\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\f0\fs17\lang1033 Only four words really!
\par 
\par }
```