# Update Excel field with long strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I have XLSX file, and I need update Description field by idProduct in that file from C# application.

To connect I use:

```
        string connectionString = string.Format(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;",
            tbFileXLS.Text.Trim());

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString); 

        string sql = string.Format(
            @"UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Description] = '{0}' WHERE [ProductID] = '{1}'",
            htmlDescription.Replace("'", "''"),
            idProduct
            );
```

But when I try to run that query

```
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
        connection.Open();
        int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

it throws an error:

> The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to
>   add. Try inserting or pasting less data.

Who knows how to resolve that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try inserting less data?

Comment: i don't insert, i update data, if i try short string like "test string" it updates successfully

Comment: If it works with a short "test string" then how long is the Description that you are trying to update? And does it contain any unusual characters? In Excel 2007 a cell can contain 32,767 characters.

Comment: Description is about few thousands chars, it could contain somespecial chars, because it's html code

Comment: I would try it with small samples of the description, then try bigger samples. Examine the descriptions as well, looking for strange characters.

Comment: I tried, no success :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984312/the-field-is-too-small-to-accept-the-amount-of-data-you-attempted-to-add-has-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do this via OleDB.

I use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; instead, find the record in the loop and update Cell[i,j] = description. It works bit slow but like a charm. Thanks!